# Docker stack conditional environment variable

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have a docker stack file that is deployed across my swarm, which have many nodes.

For a specific reason one of the nodes (lets call it Node A) has a connection to the outside (internet), and the others dont, so when deploying a container on the other nodes, I need to set the `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable.

Question is: how do I set this ONLY on the nodes with a specific label (and not on the A node)

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.6'
 
services:
  app:
    image: my_image
    ports:
      - "8033:8000"
    environment:
      - HTTP_PROXY=proxy.server.com:3128
      - HTTPS_PROXY=proxy.server.com:3128
    deploy:
      replicas: 10
      placement:
        constraints: [node.labels.app_server == app_server]
    volumes:
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
```

The only alternative so far would be to have the stack deployed with different variables, and place a constraint on deployment. But I am trying to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting those environment variables in the necessary hosts and passing them through to your container like so:

```
version: '3'
 
services:
  app:
    image: ubuntu
    environment:
      - HTTP_PROXY
      - HTTPS_PROXY
```

They will only be set in the container if they are also set in the host environment.  See [documentation here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#pass-environment-variables-to-containers).

Example/More Info:

```
# When HTTP_PROXY is set in the host environment, value is passed through to the container.
$ HTTP_PROXY=test docker-compose run app env | grep -i proxy
Creating some-nodes-only_app_run ... done
HTTP_PROXY=test

# When HTTP_PROXY is not set in the host environment, nothing is set in container.
$ docker-compose run app env | grep -i proxy
Creating some-nodes-only_app_run ... done
```

You could also write an entrypoint script to set the proxy when needed.  I would recommend checking the connectivity of the container and then falling back to a proxy if necessary, but if you want to do it based on the hostname you could use something like this:

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

PROXY_HOSTNAME=some-host
  
if [ -f /etc/host_hostname ]; then
    HOST_HOSTNAME=$(cat /etc/host_hostname)

    if [ "$HOST_HOSTNAME" = "$PROXY_HOSTNAME" ]; then
        echo "Setting fallback http proxy"
        export HTTP_PROXY=${FALLBACK_HTTP_PROXY}
    fi
fi

exec $@
```

Dockerfile

```
# test:latest
FROM ubuntu

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
  
services:
  app:
    image: test:latest
    environment:
      - FALLBACK_HTTP_PROXY=test
    volumes:
       - /etc/hostname:/etc/host_hostname:ro
```

Example run:

```
$ docker-compose run app env | grep -i http_proxy
Creating some-nodes-only_app_run ... done
Setting fallback http proxy
FALLBACK_HTTP_PROXY=test
HTTP_PROXY=test
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! At this moment I dont have access to the host machine

Comment: Okay, in that case you should probably add an entrypoint script to your image that determines if setting an `HTTP_PROXY` is necessary and then sets it (possibly based on another environment variable).

Comment: hum, ok, on the entrypoint, can I get the hostname or some node label?

Comment: Sure, you could pass it in as an environment variable, or mount `/etc/hostname` into your container somewhere and read from it.  But I was more thinking that you would test the connectivity of the container and fall back to a proxy if available.

Comment: I will test it later this week and let you know. Thanks

Comment: so I just revisited this this week, and ended up having a specific deployment for those that need proxy, it was just easier.